# Is there a way to change the Search API facet count to show a total word count instead of the count of matching fragments (documents)?

Tags: full-text-search, marklogic

I'm creating an application using Marklogic 8 and the search API. I need to create facets based on MarkLogic defined collections, but instead of the facet count giving a tally of the number of fragments (documents) which contain X number of occurrences of the keyword search performed, I need the facet count to reflect the total number of times the keyword appears in all documents in the collection.

Right now, I'm using search:search() to process the query and return a  element with the facet option enabled.

In the MarkLogic documentation, I've been looking at cts:frequency() which says: 
"If you want the total frequency instead of the fragment-based frequency (that is, the total number of occurences of the value in the items specified in the cts:query option of the lexicon API), you must specify the item-frequency option to the lexicon API value input to cts:frequency."

But, I can't get that to work.

I've tried running a query like this in query console, but it times out.

```
cts:element-values(QName("http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0", "TEI"),
"", "item-frequency",   
 cts:and-query((
    fn:collection("KirchlicheDogmatik/volume4/part3"),
    cts:word-query("lehre"))))
```

Comment: Making a call to cts:values and alike makes it return all values. Fetch the first few only, using fn:subsequence, and look at the cts:frequency of those. Also note that item-frequency defaults to ascending item-order, and fragment-frequency to descending frequency-order..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that you have a range index on `<TEI>`, which contains the entire document. Range indexes are memory-mapped, so you have essentially forced the complete text contents of your database into memory. It's hard to say exactly what's going on, but it's probably struggling to inspect the values (range indexes are designed for smaller atomic values) and possibly swapping to disk.

MarkLogic has great documentation on its indexing, so I'd recommend starting there for a better understanding on how to use them: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/concepts/indexing#id_51573

Note that even using the `item-frequency` option, results (or counts) are not guaranteed to be one-to-one with the "total number of times the keyword appears." It will report the number of "items" matching - in your example it would report on the number of `<TEI>` elements matching.

The problem of getting an exact count of terms matching a query across the whole database is actually quite hard. To get exact matching values within a document, you would need to use `cts:highlight` or `cts:walk`, which requires loading the whole document into memory. That typically works fine for a subset of documents, but ultimately to get an accurate value for the entire database, you would need to load the entire database into memory and process every document.

Nearly any approach to getting a term match count requires some kind of approximation and depends heavily on your markup. For example, if you index `<p>` (or even better `<s>`) elements, it would be possible to construct a query that uses indexes to count the number of matching paragraphs (or sentences), but that would still load an incredibly large amount of data into memory and keep it there. This is technically feasible if you are willing to allocate enough memory (and/or enough servers), but it hardly seems worth it.